# How to export multiple arrays

Tags: reactjs, export

if I have two arrays how do I export them for example:

```
const a=['a','b','c']
const b=['1','2','3']

export default a,b?
```

Answer (score 5):

Try the following while exporting:

```
const arr1 = ['a','b','c']
const arr2 = ['1','2','3']
export default { a, b }
```

And while importing

```
import { arr1, arr2 } from "path to the file";

//your code
```

Answer (score 2):

```
export const a=['a','b','c']
export const b=['1','2','3']

//Import page
import { a } from "path/to/a";
import { b } from "path/to/b";
```

`export const foo = "This is not default export"`

from each file you can have max 1 default export, but as many not default as you want. Just the import syntaxt is different

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
const a=[1,2,3,];
const b=[4,5,6];
const c=[7,8,9];

export default a;
export { b, c };
```

Then you import it with:

```
import a, {b, c} from "./pathToTheFile.js"
```

If there is a specific situation were you want to import only B and C just do this:

```
import { b, c } from "./pathToTheFile.js"
```